# Issue with grep pipeline in conditional

Tags: bash, scripting, syntax

I'm a noob with `bash` scripting I'm trying to learn but I don't know how to fix this:

```
./elleviemme.sh: line 7: unexpected token `|', conditional binary operator expected
./elleviemme.sh: line 7: syntax error near `|'
./elleviemme.sh: line 7: `if [[ lsblk | grep -qwEo ^$dvin ]]'
```

Comment: What it is you're trying to do? Have you read about the syntax of the `if`-statements and `[[ .. ]]`-conditionals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are trying to use the value of the shell variable `dvin` as an extended regular expression and want to check whether it matches at the start of any of the lines of output from the command `lsblk`.

For that, don't use `[[ ... ]]`:

```bash
if lsblk | grep -q -E -w "^$dvin"; then
   # whatever code here
fi
```

Also, note that `-q` means "quiet", i.e. no output, and that using `-q` means you won't need `-o` ("only matching") with `grep`.

You would not use `[[ ... ]]` when you want to check the exit status of some utility.  Here, you want to check how your `lsblk`+`grep` pipeline exits, which will tell you whether `grep` found a match or not.